# Constructing large PHP query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with WordPress with custom fields and trying to convert a query which was initially written for pjjtextbase (textfile database) to search a csv file for matching properties for rent/sale.

I understand that to query a custom posts in WP with custom fields I would write something like;

```
        $location = preg_replace('/^-|-$|[^-a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $_GET['location']); 
        $type = preg_replace('/^-|-$|[^-a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $_GET['type']); 
        $buyrent = preg_replace('/^-|-$|[^-a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $_GET['buyrent']); 
        $min_val =preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_GET['min_val']);
        $room_no_min = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_GET['room_no_min']); 
        // This replaces characters in the input string if need be for security reasons         

$args =

        array(
            'post_type'  => 'properties',
            'meta_query' => 

            array(
                'key'     => 'wp_location',
                'value'   => $location,
                'compare' => '=',
            )

        );
            $results = new WP_Query($args);
```

But when I look at the code the programmer wrote

```
/***** THESE VALUES NEEDED FOR SELECT BOX *****/
$locations = ptb_listUnique($info, 'Property_Location');
$property_type = ptb_listUnique($info, 'Property_Type');
$property_buy_rent = ptb_listUnique($info, 'Buy_Rent');



//check property
$query = Array();
if(!empty($_GET['location'])) { 
   $query[] = "'Property_Location' == '".$_GET['location']."'";
}
if(!empty($_GET['type'])) { 
   $query[] = "'Property_Type' == '".$_GET['type']."'";
}
if(!empty($_GET['buyrent'])) { 
   $query[] = "'Buy_Rent' == '".$_GET['buyrent']."'";
}


//check price
if(empty($_GET['buyrent']) || $_GET['buyrent']=="Buy"){
if(!empty($_GET["min_val_buy"]) && is_numeric($_GET["min_val_buy"])){
     $min_val_buy = $_GET["min_val_buy"];
}
     if(!empty($_GET["max_val_buy"]) && is_numeric($_GET["max_val_buy"])){
     $max_val_buy = $_GET["max_val_buy"];
}

$min_val_buy = min($_GET["min_val_buy"], $_GET["max_val_buy"]);
$max_val_buy = max($_GET["min_val_buy"], $_GET["max_val_buy"]);

$query[] = "'Price_Rent' >= '".$min_val_buy."'";
$query[] = "'Price_Rent' <= '".$max_val_buy."'";

}else{

if(!empty($_GET["min_val_rent"]) && is_numeric($_GET["min_val_rent"])){
     $min_val = $_GET["min_val_rent"];
}
     if(!empty($_GET["max_val_rent"]) && is_numeric($_GET["max_val_rent"])){
     $max_val = $_GET["max_val_rent"];
}

$min_val_rent = min($_GET["min_val_rent"], $_GET["max_val_rent"]);
$max_val_rent = max($_GET["min_val_rent"], $_GET["max_val_rent"]);

$query[] = "'Price_Rent' >= '".$min_val_rent."'";
$query[] = "'Price_Rent' <= '".$max_val_rent."'";

}

//check bedrooms
if(!empty($_GET["room_no_min"]) && is_numeric($_GET["room_no_min"])){
     $room_min_val = $_GET["room_no_min"];
}
if(!empty($_GET["room_no_max"]) && is_numeric($_GET["room_no_max"])){
     $room_max_val = $_GET["room_no_max"];
}

$room_min_val = min($_GET["room_no_min"], $_GET["room_no_max"]);
$room_max_val = max($_GET["room_no_min"], $_GET["room_no_max"]);

$query[] = "'No_Bedrooms' >= '".$room_min_val."'";
$query[] = "'No_Bedrooms' <= '".$room_max_val."'";

//Now build the query to search
$query = implode(' AND ', $query);
```

It dawned on me that he is not creating multiple queries and then using IMPLODE to combine them but rather creating one whole string then using IMPLODE to add the AND to create the actual query.

The custom fields I have in WP are exactly the same as the large code variable except they are preceded with wp_.

So my question is how do I go about converting his code into a WordPress query?

Comment: Looks like you want to add all of those conditions to the `meta_query` element of your `$args` array

Comment: Irrelevant comment, but the developer who wrote the original code should be taken out back and flogged mercilessly.

Comment: @Trent Care to explain why?

Comment: @Naz - he/she uses $query as an array, then implodes itself into a string... Repurposing a variable like that is (and this is just my personal opinion) is poor programming. Should have built the array, then imploded into a new variable, $query_string - from a debugging point of view, they've destroyed the original type and data of $query

Comment: More on this - it's very common to see this in production code. It's easy to be lazy :)

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query , its pretty well documented.

Comment: @David I'm already starting with a Meta Query, the question is how to create large and efficient one.

Comment: you wont, it will hammer your server. But obviously caching is needed, personally I would limit the inputs to specific ranges and cache the pages statically for each query, but it depends on how many listings and users you expect etc. Or as an alternative output the queries into a json file and work from that.